# reading input data in networkx

Tags: python, file, io, networkx

I started using python package `'networkx'` today and I'm struggling to understand how you read input data from external files.

The examples shown in the documentation deal with small networks which can be read directly from the shell.

I have a legacy file which specifies a large electric network with this format:

```
'from_node'  'to_node'  'edge_name'  'edge_capacity'  'flow_cost'
```

The next set of cards reads:

```
'node type' (source or sink), 'capacity', 'cost'
```

I want to solve the max flow problem. How can I read such input data file?

Answer (score 1):

You can read the edges using `parse_edgelist`:

```
In [1]: import networkx as nx

In [2]: lines = ["from to name capacity cost", "from1 to1 name1 capacity1 cost1"]

In [3]: G = nx.parse_edgelist(lines, data = (('name', str), ('capacity', str), ('cost', str)))

In [5]: G.edges(data=True)
Out[5]: 
[('from1', 'to1', {'capacity': 'capacity1', 'cost': 'cost1', 'name': 'name1'}),
 ('to', 'from', {'capacity': 'capacity', 'cost': 'cost', 'name': 'name'})]
```

For the nodes, you can probably just iterate over your text file and annotate the graph. The documentation provides quite a few methods for reading graphs:

http://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/readwrite.html

Comment: Thank you Juniper. It looks like is what I need to start using 'networkx'.